# Universal Analytics and no Referral Exclusion List

Tags: google-analytics, referrer

With new *Universal Analytics*, every new referral value triggers a new session:

> ### How excluding referral traffic affects your data
>
> By default, a referral automatically triggers a new session. When you
>   exclude a referral source, traffic that arrives to your site from the
>   excluded domain doesn’t trigger a new session. If you want traffic
>   arriving from a specific site to trigger a new session, don't include
>   that domain in this table.
>
> *Source: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830*

And then, there is this *Referral Exclusion List* to make *some* referrals not trigger it:

> 1. Navigate to a property. If you're not in the settings screen, click **Admin**.
> 2. Click **Tracking Info** then **Referral Exclusion List**.
> 3. Enter the *Domain*.
> 4. Click **Apply** to save.

However, I'm not able to find **Referral Exclusion List** in my **Tracking Info**. :( Here's a screenshot:

[image: No Referral Exclusion List in Tracking Info od Google Analytics]

What can be done about it? This effectively prevents me from tracking source of my conversions (payment is handled at external site).

(I even tried manually substituting `TrackingCode/` to `ReferralExclusionList/` in **Admin** dashboard URL, with no success.)

Comment: There is a `Referral Exclusion List` showing in my Universal Analytics under `.JS Tracking Info`. Try signing out, clearing your browser cache, and double-clicking on that menu item again. If that doesn't resolve it, then post a question in [this](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/analytics) forum.

Comment: After some more thought, it might be that this option isn't available in your geographical location yet.

Comment: @dan Clearing all of browser memory doesn't do any good. Even using a fresh browser in a VM doesn't. Thanks for the suggestion with Google product forum! I'll add a link to the question here, too.

Comment: @dan It's fixed now, see my answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny, maybe someone at Google is monitoring SX.

I'm seeing **Referral Exclusion List** (and other options, too) in **.js Tracking Info** now.

Whoever did this: big thanks!

Comment: I am hoping you might be able to help me out.  I have a website that uses Google Authentication.  And I have put the domain of the Google Authentication site in my Exclusion List.  But all this do was change the referrer from "accounts.google.com" to "direct".  Is there something else I need to do?